# C++ switch statement ending the menu

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Hey I am working on a Switch selection menu for my C++ programming class.  I have managed to get my menu to work, but I don't know how to stop the program on the exit selection in the menu I have made.

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char selection;

    do
    {
        cout << "  IHCC Computer Science Registration Menu\n";
        cout << "  ====================================\n";
        cout << "  1.  Welcome to Computer Programming In C++\n";
        cout << "  2.  Welcome to Java Programming\n";
        cout << "  3.  Welcome to Android Programming\n";
        cout << "  4.  Welcome to iOS Programming\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "  5.  Exit\n";
        cout << "  ====================================\n";
        cout << "  Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "Computer Programming In C++\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case '2':
                cout << "Java Programming\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;
            case '3':
                cout << "Android Programming\n" ;
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case '4':
                cout << "iOS Programming\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case '5':
                cout << "Goodbye.\n";
                break;

            default: cout <<selection << "is not a valid menu item.\n";

                cout << endl;
        }

    }while (selection != 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
while (selection != 0)
```

to:

```
while (selection != '5')
```

---

Also note that your current approach reads a single character only. In case you don't want numbers with more digits invoke the selection based on their first digit, read `int` instead:

```
int selection = 0;

do {

    cout << ...        
    cin >> selection;

    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            ...
            break;
        ...
        case 5:
            cout << "Goodbye.\n";
            break;

        default:
            ...
    }

} while (selection != 5);
```

Comment: Thanks that does work now, the program runs fine now but when i input numbers such as 23 or 43  its brings up the 2 menu from the input 23 i was wondering how i could work threw this

Comment: An even better solution may be to say `do { done = false; //stuff case 5: cout << "Goodbye.\n"; done = true; break;` //stuff } while (!done);

Answer (score 2):

LihO and sharth have the proper solution, however if the idea is to exit the program when they input 5 then I'd suggest doing this with the case:

```
case '5':
  cout << "Goodbye.\n";
  return 0;
```

It makes the program exit there and not later on in the code.

Comment: It's not best practices to have multiple returns in a method.  It would be better to use a bool or int that would exit the condition statement.

Comment: @jmstoker: As long as you don't do anything evil that requires some routines to be called upon every return path, this is perfectly valid and reasonable solution. There's nothing wrong with multiple `return` statements in a function / method.

Comment: @LihO I agree in this small program there isn't much of an issue, but it's not a good habit to get into.  It can make debugging a pain, as a `return` in the middle of a method can be overlooked and a breakpoint at the end can be missed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `selection` variable to meet the condition that you already have to exit the loop:

```
case '5':
    cout << "Goodbye.\n";
    selection = 0;
    break;
```